# AngularJS conditional class not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a register function in my controller:

```
    $scope.register = function() {
        User.register($scope.user)
            .success(function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    $scope.stage = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.message = true;
                }
            });
    }
```

I then have this HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ hidden: stage }">
        <label for="token">Confirmation Token</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the token sent to your phone" ng-model="user.token" required>
    </div>
```

Typically in jQuery I'd update the DOM by removing the class hidden if `data.success`.  Here I've used `ng-class` to conditionally apply or remove a class, but it seems it's not working.

I want the class to be there by default, and then want it to be removed if `data.success`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In the else part why are you using $scope.message = true; shouldn't you use $scope.stage = true; If you  want the class to be there by default, set $scope.stage within the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set stage to some truthy value in your controller if you want the class to be applied.

```
$scope.stage = true;
User.register($scope.user)
...
```

And if all you're aiming to do it show/hide the element, you could use ng-show or ng-hide instead of ng-class (but you'd still need to set stage to true):

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="stage">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{true: 'hidden'}[stage]">
```